# How to convert jquery code into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Yesterday I have put the question which was answered correctly but now I want to convert that same code into javascript. I have made some changes but its not work

working code- http://jsfiddle.net/SXzyR/8/

mycode- http://jsfiddle.net/SXzyR/11/

Comment: This type of question, where you're looking to refactor working code, should be posted on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: jQuery _is_ JavaScript... but I take it you're trying to ditch jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `this.id` instead of [`document.getElementById(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) to get the id string where `this` is a DOM element.

Comment: why document.getElementById(this) not working

Comment: @amit, because this references the _element_, not the _id of the element_

Answer (score 1):

Please read some tutorials about jQuery. [This](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery) is a good start, also have a look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials).

jQuery isn't another language, it's a library for JavaScript. Considering the following line from your "translated" code:

```
txtval(document.getElementById(this)
```

Instead of writing document.getElementById you can simply use jQuery to write

```
txtval($(this))
```

as in the first example (working code).

Also you are mixing jQuery with "native" JavaScript/DOM functions in your code. Don't reinvent the wheel, use jQuery to accomplish your task.

Comment: tried but not working txtval(document.getElementById(this)

Comment: @amit try `document.getElementById(this.id)` or `document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'))` to pass the id, not the DOM element...